# Getting 401 when using nuxt/apollo with github API

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo

I am trying to pull some data from my pinned repos using the github v4 API within Nuxt.js I have set up the following as per the docs:

```
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/color-mode',
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
  ],
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
        authenticationType: 'Bearer',
        tokenName: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,
      },
    },
  },
```

My query in another component is:

```
export default {
  apollo: {
    opensource: gql`
      query github {
        user(login: "mrpbennett") {
          pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
            edges {
              node {
                ... on GitHub_Repository {
                  name
                  description
                  url
                  primaryLanguage {
                    name
                    color
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
```

But I am getting the following `Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 401`  which presents me with

```
function ApolloError(_a) {
      var graphQLErrors = _a.graphQLErrors,
          networkError = _a.networkError,
          errorMessage = _a.errorMessage,
          extraInfo = _a.extraInfo;

      var _this = _super.call(this, errorMessage) || this;

      _this.graphQLErrors = graphQLErrors || [];
      _this.networkError = networkError || null;

      if (!errorMessage) {
        _this.message = generateErrorMessage(_this);
      } else {
        _this.message = errorMessage;
      }

      _this.extraInfo = extraInfo;
      _this.__proto__ = ApolloError.prototype;
      return _this;
    }
```

Within file `bundle.umd.js`

I know the query works as I have used the same one within Gatsby. Any ideas where I am going wrong with the authentication?